# Cost center numbering

Tags: list

I'm trying to put together a simple quote database with confirmed quotes sent to customers. Some quotes are for services, that share the same cost center number, and some quotes have their own unique cost center number. For example, unique quotes are numbered 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003... and quotes for standardized services have a specific cost center numbered with 201, 202, 203 etc. Several quotes therefore can have the same cost center number but majority is unique.

Entering cost center number manually is a bad idea because someone might accidentally repeat a unique cost center number (which would also need to be listed somewhere) and cause problems to our accounting. I'm thinking two ways: one is a calculated columns with automatic numbering where the standardized quote's cost center would be enter manually by overwriting the calculated forumla for an item (if this is possible at all) and the other option would be a lookup column to a separate database with cost center numbers generated. The problem is, the standardized quotes cost center numbers can repeat, and unique quotes shouldn't.

I'm a total self-taught noob with SharePoint, had no professional trainings so I would kindly ask all prepared to assist to be as clear as possible in their instructions. :)

A huge thank you to anyone trying to help in this matter!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be a good idea to pull the cost centre number from the term store.
Try to Google managed metadata and Peter kalmstrom for a good primer